# How to solve NoReverseMatch in django1.8.6

Tags: python, django

Recently I wrote an app called notebook, and I came across this NoReverseMatch issue.Really hope someone could help me out.
Here are my codes.
in views.py:

```
def note_add(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NoteForm()
    category = CategoryForm()
    if form.is_valid() and category.is_valid():
        data1 = form.cleaned_data
        data2 = category.cleaned_data
        category_name = data2['category_name']
        for category_list in category_name.split():
            Category.objects.get_or_create(category_name=category_list.strip())
        title = data1['title']
        content = data1['content']
        note = Note(title=title, content=content)
        note.save()
        id = Note.objects.order_by('-id')[0].id
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/notebook/note_add/%s' % id)
else:
    form = NoteForm()
    category = CategoryForm()
return render_to_response('notebook/note_add.html',{'form':form, 'category':category})
```

in notebook/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.note_list, name='note_list'),
    url(r'^/note_add/$,', views.note_add, name='note_add'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.note_detail, name='note_detail'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.note_category,   name='note_category'),
]
```

The problem description is

```
NoReverseMatch at /notebook/

Reverse for 'note_add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notebook//note_add/$,']
```

Comment: Which url did you expect it to match

Comment: Remove the leading / `url(r'^note_add/$,', views.note_add, name='note_add')`

Comment: That error is not coming from that code, because you are not using `reverse` or the template `{% url %}` tag anywhere.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's still not working

Comment: @Sayse the 'note_add' .I wrote {%url 'note_add' %}  in an HTML.And the problem shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first "/" in urls.

```
url(r'^note_add/$,', views.note_add, name='note_add'),
```

Like that.

From what i have seen "no reverse match" was usually because of errors in urls

Comment: It's still not working. It still occurred the same problem

Comment: You should also remove the comma at the end of the string i.e. `r'^note_add/$'`